# How can I have a continuous firebase cloud function for a continuous stream of data?

Tags: firebase, twitter, google-cloud-functions, twitter-streaming-api

I need to use the Twitter Stream API to stream tweet data to my firebase cloud function like this:

```
client.stream('statuses/filter', params,  stream => {

  stream.on('data', tweet => {
    console.log(tweet);
  })

  stream.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error)
  })

})
```

The stream is continuous but the firebase cloud function shuts down after a certain period of time. What solution could I make use of to be able to continuously receive the stream data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Functions have a max running time of 540 seconds [as documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#time_limits). You would have to look at probably using a [Compute Engine Instance from Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) where you can have code running without limits. Or you could look at using the [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) to run your function every x time to get new tweets.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I think I will either use a Compute Engine Instance or use another platform such as Heroku to run the backend.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted response suggests running GCE and while it's certainly correct, I'd like to point out that anyone who was interested in Cloud Functions - a serverless solution - might find GAE (App Engine) much more viable for streaming data.

Our application utilises App Engine Standard as an ingestion service and it works like a charm - removing overhead required by GCE. If advanced networking features are required by your app App Engine Flexible or GKE (Kubernetes Engine) might also be something to look at!